# `&`や`=`を含む文字列を検索条件のパラメーターにするとAPI接続で値が取得できない

Tags: swift, api

`SwiftUI`で、`API`接続でデータを取得し利用するアプリを開発しています。

SwiftUIで開発中のアプリから、API接続でGETの方法でデータを取得する際に、検索条件のパラメーターが`&`や`=`を含む文字列になる場合、データを取得することができません。

---

例えば、
`http://sample.com/api/book/`
というベースのエンドポイントがあり、`?url=`というように、URLの文字列を検索の条件とする場合：

①：以下のようにパラメーターを設定すると値が取得できますが、
[http://sample.com/api/book/?url=`https://nicebook.com/detail/id/106639`](http://sample.com/api/book/?url=%60https://nicebook.com/detail/id/106639%60)

②：以下の場合は取得できません
[http://sample.com/api/book/?url=`https://nicebook.com/detail/?id=106639&category=history`](http://sample.com/api/book/?url=%60https://nicebook.com/detail/?id=106639&category=history%60)

②の場合、パラメーターとして設定している文字列に`?`,`=`の記号が含まれ、こちらも検索の条件とされてしまい、期待している動きにならないと思うのですが、このような場合どのような対策方法があるでしょうか？

---

API接続時のコードは以下のとおりです。

```
func fetchApiData() {

    let url_1 = "https://nicebook.com/detail/id/106639"
    let url_2 = "https://nicebook.com/detail/?id=106639&category=history"

    var endpoint = "http://sample.com/api/book/?url=" + url_1 // OK
    // var endpoint = "http://sample.com/api/book/?url=" + url_2 NG

    var encodeEndpoint = endpoint.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""

    // Set up the URL request
    guard let url = URL(string: encodeEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL)

    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in

        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET")
            return
        }
        // make sure we got data
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }

        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do{ self.bookInfos = try JSONDecoder().decode([BookInfo].self, from: responseData)
                print(self.bookInfos as Any) // url_2で行うと値が取れない（コンソール -> []）
            }catch{
                print("Error: did not decode")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

---

[こちら](https://qiita.com/yum_fishing/items/db029c097197e6b27fba)の記事を参考に、パラメーターとなるURLのエンコードを別にエンコードする方法も試しましたが、うまく取得できません。

```
let url_2 = "https://nicebook.com/detail/?id=106639&category=history"
url_2.addEndpoint.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!
var endpoint = "http://sample.com/api/book/?url=" + url_2

var encodeEndpoint = endpoint.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) ?? ""
```

---

Swift 5.0

Answer (score 1):

下記のように編集する事でかいけつできました。

```
var urlComps = URLComponents(string: endpoint)!
urlComps.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "url", value: url_2)]
guard let url = urlComps.url else {
    print("Error: cannot create URL")
    return
}
```